# Can we send iMessages hooked up to a backend application?

Tags: ios, twilio, imessage

We’re hoping to use iMessages as part of our application. We want every user to be able to iMessage us. Our backend will then process that message. We have two questions:

1. Is there a package to accomplish this? Do we need to apply to something like Apple Business Chat?
2. If iMessage is not possible, we’re looking at text message sending services like Twilio, though that would add a great deal of cost. Has anyone had a great experience with them?